# Determine if new docker container available on docker hub

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running a website.

The container is updated by the build machine, and pushed to docker hub.

Without using webhooks, or poking the docker hub API the only solution I found to determine if a new container is available, is by parsing the output of `docker pull`, and looking for a string suggesting a new container is available. There is no exit code indicating no new docker container is available.

Besides parsing output to stdout, is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: If it fits to your needs, you can leave the automatic update stuff to watchtower project: https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/watchtower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up here again recently, and watchtower worked out very well.